# Windows.open: how to send HTML code?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I need to send HTML code of **myDiv** using PHP or jQuery but I don't know if it is possible.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <strong>text</strong> <!-- send this line -->
</div>

$script = <<<JS
    window.open('/people?var1=$myDiv');
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

I am using the Yii2 framework.

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings? How to get the contents of an element?

Comment: How to get this exactly string: <strong>text</strong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `html()` method to get html.

```
$("#myDiv").html();
```